# Creating timeline: how to get next event?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, timeline

I found the wiki [page](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist/wiki/DP---Timeline-Trees) about creating time lines but it is very short and incompleted. I managed to create cypher code for adding events to the timeline:

```
MERGE (y:YEAR{year: {y} })
CREATE UNIQUE y-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m:MONTH{month:{m}    })
CREATE UNIQUE m-[:HAS_DAY]->  (d:DAY  {day:  {d}    })     
CREATE UNIQUE d-[:HAS_EVENT]->(e:EVENT{desc: {desc} })
WITH y AS y
MATCH n RETURN n
```

It seems to work OK but I also need to be able for any event to get next one. I'm not sure  how can I establish horizontal (i.e. between months, days, events) links in cypher and If I manage to do it I will need to destroy this links when I insert a new event between two other events.
If I don't establish horizontal links the code to get next event in timeline will be rather awkward I think. Or not? What is the best way too implement it?

Comment: congrats, this was the 5000th question tagged with `neo4j` on SO :-)

Comment: The Page you found is WIP of GraphPatterns. The page in the manual is probably more helpful http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html

Comment: Usually I link the time-tree horizontally and not the events themselves. So you'd go along the time-tree in sequential order and collect the events beneath.

Comment: If your resolution is only to the day, you can also create the time tree upfront, see my blog post: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/04/importing-forests-into-neo4j/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [How to filter edges by time stamp in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748556/how-to-filter-edges-by-time-stamp-in-neo4j/24750083#24750083)

The modeling guideline for time is to use time tree hierarchies for aggregations `(Year)->(Month)->(Day)`, timestamps for ranges, and linked lists for retrieving relative N nodes from any other node (get last 5, get next 5).

[image: Timeline with linked list]